# UE4(С++) Сan I find out which key was pressed

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

In the project I need to process pressing numbers, for this I created a special Action Map: [ActionMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWLMQ.jpg)

After I announce the click handler:

```
PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("EnterNum", IE_Pressed, this, &AMainPlayer::EnterNum);
```

Can I know which key was pressed or I should create a handler for each number?

Comment: Please give some [mre] in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you mean, but unfortunately you have to create a separate method for each number. For example, you can have an action mapping like this:

```
Name: Num0
  0
  Num_0
Name: Num1
  1
  Num_1
...........
```

Then bind every single number with the corresponding method.

Although I would agree it would be a very useful feature to get the exact number.